# How to access functions of a remote hardware device through a web interface?

Tags: c#, android, .net, windows, remote-access

I come from the web development background, but currently facing a project, which somehow touches the topic of remote hardware manipulation from the web interface.

**Prerequisites**

- Numerous remote tablet devices, operated on (a) Windows and (b) Android OS
- React web application

**Goal**: to develop a React-based web application, which would be able to perform certain actions:

1. Retrieve system information (e.g. uptime, real-time online/offline status, system logs and errors)
2. Perform system methods, such as reboot the device or upload new file to a target device file system

**Questions**: What is the best way to access remote device system methods from a client web application?

**Assumptions**: I assume (*and I might be completely wrong!*) the best practice is to:

1. Develop a Web API based on .NET (for Windows) and Java (for Android) in order to provide an interface to communicate with for the client application in a form of a REST API or similar.
2. Websockets for real-time status update regarding online/offline status (?)

The rest is a big question mark for me. I would appreciate any help or direction that I have to research further.

Comment: You can't.  Remember the webpage is actually running on the client machine so you are not remote.  The device is local.  If you are really trying to access a device on the server is has to be run as admin because the clients only have GUEST accounts.  So for code to be secure you want to create a separate app that only accesses the device on the server and run that code with AS ADMIN.  Then from webpage call the new app to access the device so you aren't giving users ADMIN access on the server.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer. From what I understood, it fits my assumption #1: you create a separate application (read: API) and call it from the webpage, as you have suggested. Did I misunderstand your suggestion?

Comment: What you did is correct.